# PNG files in SO questions

Tags: png

Can we prevent PNG files from being uploaded to SO?  Or at least suggest that they be pasted in as text and surrounded by braces?

It is very difficult for me to convert PNG data to usable XLS or TXT that can be used to duplicate the users problems.

Comment: Did you mean to post this in [meta]?

Comment: Yes, please transfer it.tkx